# How to get return value from servlet to c#

Tags: c#, servlets

How can I get the return value from servlet to c#? I passed parameter to servlet using

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                         .Create("http://localhost:8080/value/Get_value?p_value=" + 
                                      passedValue);    
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Then servlet will process and passed the return value to c#.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Writing the HTTP response in the servlet code, or reading the HTTP response in the C# code?

Comment: I manage to send the parameter to servlet to process. The servlet then will return the string which I need it in c# code. The problem is I don't know how to get the return value from servlet to c#.

Comment: That's not a servlet problem then. You would have exactly the same problem with every other resource like `"http://google.com"`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to read the response buffer (stream).

```
...
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using (StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
 {
 string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
 Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
```

Comment: Meaning what I need to do is to add the streamReader from the response? Do I need to add anything in my servlet? Currently I add PrintWriter out=response.getWriter(); and used out.println(value); in servlet.